# Where did the mathematician go?

Tags: mathematics, steganography, letter-sequence

Two mathematicians were discussing their recent holdays. The first mathematician exclaims

> I was on an all inclusive trip to lanserote for two weeks.

The second mathematician, slightly ashamed, didn't want to disclose where he went after that, so he wrote a puzzle for his colleague to solve.

> This is where i went for my holiday this year.
>
> ```
> Lanzdsfukr/edeasoenrnso,rltkyjurio
> ```

Where did the second mathematician go on holiday.

Comment: Are any apparent typos ("lanserote" instead of "Lanzarote", lowercase "i") relevant?

Comment: @kovacsur Not sure, but it does stand out to me that the first 4 letters of the coded message are the same as the correct spelling of `Lanzarote`.

Comment: There are no typos that i can see. Let me add another tag to give some clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think he went to

> [Llandudno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llandudno)

Reasoning

> If we consider the letters in the Fibonacci numbered positions: 
>  1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34, 
>  in the string, it spells Llandudno 
>  **Lan**z**d**sf**u**kr/e**d**easoenr**n**so,rltkyjuri**o**

Comment: That is exactly where he went. I didnt know if i explain the puzzle correctly. Or if the puzzle wasnt constructed well enough.

Comment: I think you explained it fine. I think people may have been confused by the spelling "lanserote" in the second sentence, where it's usually "Lanzarote". Nice puzzle.

Comment: @hexomino As a bonus, "Llanet" is a female forename...  The first scientist was actually visiting his girlfriend!